# how to get class name of class that injects something

Tags: java, logging, guice

I want to use a custom logger (slf4j) injected by guice within the constructor. I found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6604071/guice-log4j-custom-injection-does-not-support-logging-within-the-constructor) to achieve that. But probably there is a better way by just implementing a provider for logger. With this a logger is injected like all other stuff `@Inject Logger logger`.
The only thing i need is the name of the class that requests injection. Is there a way to get this name within a provider (Who called me? - method)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a nice way to do this in Guice 3.  Guice 4 (in beta right now) has `ProvisionListener` which makes this possible, though still difficult.  I wrote a library for it called [Sangria](http://tavianator.com/2014/04/announcing-sangria/).